# Probability of the waiting time M/G/1 and G/M/1 queue

Tags: stochastic-processes, laplace-transform, queueing-theory

**Task:**

Given is
$F(t)=1-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2t}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}$ and $\rho=\frac{1}{2}$.

My task is to calculate

1) $\mathbb{E}[W]$, $\mathbb{P}(W>0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W>1)$ in an M/G/1 queue with $A_i$ i.i.d. $\sim$ exp and $B_i$ i.i.d. $\sim$ $F(t)$.

2) $\mathbb{E}[W]$, $\mathbb{P}(W>0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W>1)$ in an G/M/1 queue with $A_i$ i.i.d. $\sim$ $F(t)$ and $B_i$ i.i.d. $\sim$ exp.

W denotes the waiting time.

**My ideas so far:**

For $\mathbb{E}[W]$ in task 1) I used the formular

$$
\mathbb{E}[W]=\frac{\rho}{1-\rho} \frac{\mathbb{E}[B^2]}{2 \mathbb{E}[B]}
$$
and calculated the first of second moment of the service time $B$ with the Laplace-Stieljtes Transform.
My result for this is
$$
\tilde{B}(s)=\frac{1}{s+2} + \frac{1}{3s+2}.
$$
which gives 
$\mathbb{E}[W]= \frac{5}{4}.$
Moreover, I know the Laplace Stieltjes Transform for the waiting time.

Can I use this to calculate $\mathbb{P}(W>0)$ and $\mathbb{P}(W>1)$? If yes, how?
What can I do for the G/M/1 queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For a general M/G/1 you only have an expression for the Laplace transform of the waiting time (Pollaczek-Khinchine formula), and so typically there are no explicit expressions for the probability $\mathbb{P}(W>t)$. The exception is the atom at zero which can be computed for example by Little's law:
$$
\mathbb{P}(W>0)=\mathbb{E}\mathbf{1}(W>0)=\lambda \mathbb{E}[B]=\rho.
$$
Other probabilities you can only approximate by numerical inversion of the Laplace Transform.

2) For the G/M/1 it is actually easier because the sojourn time is exponentially distributed (as in the M/M/1 queue). This can be shown by using the fact that the queue length upon arrival is geometric with parameter $\sigma$ that is the solution of
$$
\sigma=\tilde{A}(\mu(1-\sigma)),
$$
where $\tilde{A}(s)=\mathbb{E}[e^{-sA}]$ is the LST of the inter-arrival times. The sojourn time is then given by a geometric sum of exponential random variables with rate $\mu$ and so it is also exponential with rate $\mu(1-\sigma)$. 
The waiting time distribution is then (again, as in the M/M/1 queue) a mixture of an atom with probability $1-\rho$ at zero and an exponential distribution with probability $\rho$. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb{P}(W> t)=e^{-\mu(1-\sigma)t}.
$$

*The above assumes that you are familiar with the standard transform analysis of the queues, otherwise some more details are required and I suggest going over the relevant chapters in a queueing theory text book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!For the M/G/1 queue, I was also aware that I can compute the expectation using the Laplace transform of the waiting time (Pollaczek-Khinchine formula), but I have one major problem with that: The denominator of the Laplace-Stieljtes Transform is $\lambda \tilde{B}(s)+s-\lambda$, so the derivative has $(\lambda \tilde{B}(s)+s-\lambda)^2$ in the denominator. If I now set s=0, then I get $(\lambda \cdot 1+0-\lambda)^2$ since $\tilde{B}(s)=1$. Hence the denominator is zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not wrong, but notice that the numerator also goes to zero. You need to apply L'Hôpital's rule (twice!) to get the result.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but do you have any book recommendations for numerical inversions of the Laplace transform?

Comment: I found this very helpful: http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/Fall03/chapter.pdf